# MySQL select optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

A table with a few Million rows, something like this:

```
my_table (
  `CONTVISITID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NODE_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NODE_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONT_NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HITS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLIENT_TYPE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` bigint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PLAY_TIMES` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_PUBLISH_TIME` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CONTVISITID`),
  KEY `cont_visit_contid` (`CONT_ID`),
  KEY `cont_visit_createtime` (`CREATE_TIME`),
  KEY `cont_visit_publishtime` (`FIRST_PUBLISH_TIME`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57676834 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I had a query that I have managed to optimize to the following departing from a flat select:

```
SELECT a.cont_id, SUM(a.hits) 
FROM  (
SELECT cont_id,hits,type,first_publish_time 
FROM my_table 
where create_time > '2017-03-10 00:00:00' 
AND first_publish_time>1398310263000 
AND type=1) as a group by a.cont_id 
order by sum(HITS) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Can this be further optimized?

Edit:
I started with a FLAT select like I mentioned before, what I mean by flat select not to have a composite select like my current one. Instead of the single select that someone responded with. A single select is twice slower, so not viable in my case.

Edit2: I have a DBA friend who suggested me to change the query to this:

```
SELECT a.cont_id, SUM(a.hits) 
FROM  (
 SELECT cont_id,hits
 FROM my_table 
 where create_time > '2017-03-10 00:00:00' 
  AND first_publish_time>1398310263000 
  AND type=1) as a group by a.cont_id 
order by sum(HITS) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

As I do not need the fields extra (`type,first_publish_time`) and the TMP table is smaller, this makes the query faster about about 1/4 total time of the fastest version I have. He also suggested to add a composite index between (create_time, cont_id, hits). He says with this index I will get really good performance, but I have not done that as this is a production DB and the alter might affect replication. I will post results once done.

Comment: This is probably a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is the sub query absolutely necessary? You probably need some indexes on the fields you are selecting on too. (hard to read the table spec)

Comment: There is no need of subquery. you can do the entire thing in a single query

Comment: You should add `type` to the composite index you have as it appears to be un-indexed.

Comment: Without the subquery is slower. Please do not mark down without testing or knowing what you are talking about. I will ask on code review then.

Comment: @Dave Becker type only has 3 values 1, 2 or 3, so is not really very useful I think? Also keep present that every index added slows down other stuff like insert update.

Comment: If I had 3 values spread across "a few million rows" I'd want them indexed if I used them in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks i will try.

Comment: I'd be tempted to create a composite index like you have but without `CONTVISITID`. Because that value is unique it may be bloating your index and it is not in the where clause. Worth a try...

Comment: @Dave Becker, the answer to 3 values spread across "a few million rows" I'd want them indexed is: NO, not good due to too much over head for to little advantage.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(type, first_publish_time)
INDEX(type, create_time)
```

Then do

```
SELECT cont_id, SUM(hits) AS tot_hits 
    FROM my_table 
    where create_time > '2017-03-10 00:00:00' 
      AND first_publish_time > 1398310263000 
      AND type = 1
    group by cont_id 
    order by tot_hits DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Start the index with any `=` filters (`type`, in this case); then you get one chance to us a range.

The reason for 2 indexes -- The Optimizer will look at statistics and decide which look better based on the values given.

Consider shrinking the `BIGINTs` (8 bytes) to some smaller `INT` type.  Saving space will help speed, especially if the table is too big to be cached.

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;`.

Comment: The query is slower, the index might help, the big int is required.

Comment: Let us know if the indexes help.